# What's up with these 2 versions of Umineko? There's something about 'original' and then 'console'

Tags: umineko-when-they-cry

Left from [here](https://youtu.be/hpklTEqsVNk?t=2133), and right from [here](https://youtu.be/boIFcAK6Krw?t=389):

[image]

According to the fandom page for each character, there's something about [original vs console](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/Battler_Ushiromiya) eg for the Battler page:

[image]

But when I look up 'original' or 'console' on the fandom, I don't really see anything.

Maybe something to do with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Umineko_When_They_Cry_titles)?

> The Umineko no Naku Koro ni Saku collection of prior content and the new episode 9 was released in October 2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [original](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%86%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AD%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E9%A0%83%E3%81%AB#%E5%8E%9F%E4%BD%9C) PC release of Umineko no Naku koro ni, by doujin group 07th Expansion, was a doujin game released at ComiKets 72 through 79, releasing each of the original 8 arcs one at a time, from August 2007 through December 2010. The character designs were done by Ryukishi07 himself, also the writer and director of the games.

[Alchemist](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B1%E3%83%9F%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88_(%E4%BC%81%E6%A5%AD)), a japanese port producer, who had previously worked on the PS3 port of Higurashi no Naku koro ni Matsuri (which packaged both the question and answer arcs in a single game), released the first PS3 port of Umineko which included all 4 question arcs, with updated art by [FFC](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFC_(%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC)), on December 2010, a few weeks before the last Answer arc was released on ComiKet 79, probably done for cross promotion. This is the art referred to as "console" in the wiki. They later released the port of the Answer arcs in December 2011. This version, although originally planned to have a new ending, ending up only having updated art.

You can also see in the wiki a Pachinko tab for character artwork, this is indeed the art used for the Umineko pachinko games in Japan, but was also used for the official English PC release of Umineko, available on Steam, this version also includes the original art by Ryukishi07.

[Umineko no Naku Koro ni Saku](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/Umineko_no_Naku_Koro_ni_Saku) is the latest release from 07th Expansion for PC, which includes all original 8 arcs along with a few extra arcs and the short story compilations previously released (Tsubasa and Hane). It features art by Ryukishi07, but it also has a PS4 release, although since Alchemist went bankrupt, this port was made by ENTERGRAM, but they kept the same character designer as the previous console ports, FFC.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%86%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AD%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E9%A0%83%E3%81%AB), it seems:

- Original = [原作](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%86%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AD%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E9%A0%83%E3%81%AB#%E5%8E%9F%E4%BD%9C) from 2007 ([sample](https://www.suruga-ya.jp/product/detail/186011244))
- Console = [PlayStation 3](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%86%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AD%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E9%A0%83%E3%81%AB#%E7%A7%BB%E6%A4%8D%E7%89%88) from 2010 ([sample](https://www.inside-games.jp/article/img/2010/09/14/44378/157278.html))

Comment: Oh wow I have to see the Japanese wikipedia to understand. Unbelievable. Thanks sundowner. Happy Easter. Soooo the thing is the original was a PC game (Hardly consider this a 'game' of course, but whatever) while console is a re-release 3 years later in PS3, where besides a different platform, they also made things higher quality art?

Comment: @BCLC From what I understand, it was originally a 同人ゲーム, which means a group of amateurs made the game and sold it online or in [comic market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comiket) just on their own. Then they tied up with professional game makers, who remade it and released in ps3. I don't know how exactly they are related (complete remake or not).

Comment: Aaaaaaaaahhhhhhhhhh I think I read about this. So it's something like some fans remade it in higher art quality but then the Ryukishi07 company bought it from them?

Comment: The console port was managed by Alchemist, not 07th Expansion. What @sundowner meant is that 07th Expansion itself is a doujin group, the original PC version of Umineko was indeed released as a doujin game at ComiKet. Then sometime after and following the success of the Higurashi console port, Alchemist produced the PS3 ports of both the question and answer arcs with updated art.

Comment: Thanks @paulnamida Happy Easter! Oh wow...doujin means amateur right? Is it common to get a manga/an anime adaptation of your game when you're in a doujin group?

Comment: It's most definitely NOT common,but as they say, people will buy it as long as it's interesting, and some doujin circles can turn that into reality, see ZUN and the Touhou series, or Type-Moon and the Nasuverse (Tsukihime and Fate series mostly). There's smaller examples as well, like some doujin manga being picked up for official publication like Tawawa on Monday which started with the author just uploading art in twitter/pixiv and self-publishing them as artbooks at Comiket. This is a lot more common than getting the full mixed media treatment.