# 2 versions of The Quintessential Quintuplets where Nino's eyes are coloured differently (S02E10)

Tags: anime-production, the-quintessential-quintuplets

I happened to obtain 2 separate versions of The Quintessential Quintuplets and I noticed in S02E10 when Nino wants to group up with Fuutarou, Nino's eyes are coloured differently...

**Question**: What's up with this? It's been pointed out to me that 1 is probably an error that was later fixed. But which is the error, and why?

Version 1: Nino's eyes are dark blue.

> [image]

Version 2: Nino's eyes are baby blue.

> [image]

I'm guessing it's *unlike* the [2 versions of Umineko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66700/whats-up-with-these-2-versions-of-umineko-theres-something-about-original-a)...

---

In case relevant:

In both versions of the anime, Nino's eyes are baby blue a few seconds later when Nino says 'Stay out of this, Fuu-kun.'

> [image]

In the coloured manga, Nino's eyes are just dark blue

> [image]

Comment: What's the color of her eyes in other episodes?

Comment: @Michael the usual [dark blue](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67143/whats-so-good-about-being-called-by-her-first-name)?

Comment: I swear this exact question has been asked before. Did you delete it and repost it? Or am I just experiencing deja vu?

Comment: @F1Krazy It was forcefully deleted and then I reposted it.

Comment: It's *really* not a good idea to repost deleted questions, but without any context, I'm not going to push the issue any further.

Comment: @F1Krazy 'It's really not a good idea to repost deleted questions' --> Why? Note they are auto deleted not deleted by moderators. Forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd one is probably a mistake. The quints' eyes are all ultramarine blue but would become periwinkle blue when they are in a surprise or suddenly excited mode. The abrupt mood change of Nino in this scene should happen after she has suddenly stood up. So, the first version is consistent with the setting while the 2nd is less consistent.

Examples where the quints' eyes change their color.

1. S2E5

   before
   [image]

   when Uesugi approached her
   [image]
2. S2E5

   before
   [image]

   when her dad said the reason is his hatred
   [image]
3. S2E7

   before
   [image]

   when Uesugi asked her reason to shop in a store far from her apartment
   [image]
4. S2E7

   before
   [image]

   when Uesugi asked whom she had a crush on
   [image: strong text]
5. S2E8

   before
   [image]

   when Uesugi checked her thigh for bruise under the kimono
   [image]